# Playing local files with HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video

Is it possible to play a video file which users have stored locally on their computer on a website? The path of the file is not known to me, I want the users to choose the file with a "choose file" dialog.

The goal is to show overlays over the actual video files, but usually the video files will be too large to let the users upload them, such that I could process them on the server. So, I want the user to select the file from the local computer, directly play it with HTML5 in the browser and generate the overlays with Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. You can achieve this with the HTML5 File API:

```
var file = $('file')[0].files[0];
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
$('video')[0].src = url;

<input type="file" id="file" accept="video/*" />
<video controls autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Though this answer works perfectly, it just allows the user to play a local file within the actual window. It creates a web sandbox's reference to the local file, so the file displayed is that sandbox's reference. When the user closes the window, the sandbox's reference is deleted, so it's not a constant file URL (it cannot be stored as a local file URL). Next time you try to load this URL, if stored, will get a GET error. I know he specifies the user to select the file, so this answer is correct, but if he had thought of store the URL, it won't be possible.